# самый последний ряд

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте в собеседованиях встретился с такому вопросу "Как найти самый последний ряд" искал в интернете не нашел что то понятного если не сложно скажите как это сделать?.

Comment: Подзапросом оставить последний ряд. Как вариант пронумеровать, а обверткой хвост `order by нумарация desc  limit 1`

Comment: привет я не mysql разработчик если не сложно можно более подробнее

Comment: Прежде чем искать "самый последний ряд", надо дать определение, что это такое. Это в кинотеатре понятно, о чём речь... а в терминах БД вообще нет понятия "ряд".

Comment: Плюсую @Akina. ТС, человек, задающий этот вопрос, либо некомпетентен, либо троль, либо вы исказили его вопрос.

Comment: @Akina ВЫ ПОНЯЛИ О ЧЕМ МОЙ ВОПРОС?

Comment: Увы, нет. О чём собственно и сообщил. Ожидая уточнения заданного вопроса, а не задания встречного. Но если речь о последней записи при некоей сортировке - то она же будет первая при реверсной сортировке, и в этом случае получить её - не проблема. См. ответ @NTP. PS. Не надо кричать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в таблице есть поле с `auto_increment`(допустим `id`), то таким запросом:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      table
ORDER BY  auto_increment_field DESC
LIMIT     1;
```

P.S. `auto_increment` предполагает наличие уникального номера для каждой строки. Можно конечно и для любого другого столбца сделать такой запрос, но `DESC` сортирует строки и не факт, что последняя запись будет самой новой.